# Visualization and navigation through a Pareto front

Tags: data-visualization, interactive-visualization

I've recently extended my genetic algorithm in such a way that it constructs a Pareto front, instead of weighing the different quality dimensions.
The quality dimensions are not related to 'spacial' information, so no natural x,y,z candidates. They are real quality dimensions (for instance recall, precision, cost, etc.).

Now I'm faced with the challenge of providing visualization and navigation options to the user to investigate the Pareto front of candidates. Currently I'm using simple navigators per dimension and I've implemented a simple dot plot like below:

[Example of used chart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/images/XYSplineRendererDemo1a.png)

I've seen research that uses a 3D version of the dot plot as visualization aid.

However, I'm keen to know of other visualization solutions or best practices regarding Pareto fronts.